# Reuse search box for finding strings in different editor windows in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I believe in Luna I could use an opened find/replace (search) dialog box for searching in any active file. In Neon, it seems that the box is bound to the editor window active when I opened the box. So if I hit CTRL_F while editing file A, and search for "public", I find the matches. Now if I change the active window to file B, and do the same search, I do not find the matches. Next if I make A active again, the matches succeed once more. The scope is all and I am doing a wrap search.   The problem of finding "public" occurs for example if B and A have the contents: public class B { } and "public class A { }" respectively

If this is truly a problem, I am sure others would have identified it too.
But Googling for "reuse/use search box for multiple files eclipse neon" leads to questions about how to search for/replace a string in multiple files. This is not what I want. I want to find the string in the current file, and simply reuse the box for each active file, with the same or different strings to be matched. Maybe in Luna I changed the default search behavior, and if so, I do not remember the details. (The search settings are the same)

This is my first StackOverflow post so sorry if I have not dotted my is and crossed my ts :-)

Comment: Provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: The behavior of the Find/Replace dialog has not changed. This works fine here.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Committers version and this is the behavior on both my desktop and laptop. Maybe I have taken it to a buggy state. Thanks greg449.

Comment: Jerqen Hier: The problem of finding "public" occurs for example if B and A have the contents: public class B {

} and "public class A {

}"  respectively